# Private subnets cannot access internet via NAT gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-aws-modules

I have an Elastic beanstalk app with Docker platform that's in a private subnets and I need the ec2 instances in that private subnet to be able to access the internet to be able to download docker images.

EB is not able to download public docker images

```
2023/05/26 20:49:51.618533 [INFO] Pulling valhalla ... 
Pulling valhalla ... error

ERROR: for valhalla  manifest for gisops/valhalla:latest not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown
manifest for gisops/valhalla:latest not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown

2023/05/26 20:49:51.618555 [WARN] failed to execute command: docker-compose pull, retrying...
2023/05/26 20:49:51.618565 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c docker-compose pull
2023/05/26 20:49:54.895191 [INFO] Pulling valhalla ... 
Pulling valhalla ... error

ERROR: for valhalla  manifest for gisops/valhalla:latest not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown
manifest for gisops/valhalla:latest not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown

2023/05/26 20:49:54.895227 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [Docker Specific Build Application]. Stop running the command. Error: failed to pull docker images: Command /bin/sh -c docker-compose pull failed with error exit status 1. Stderr:Pulling valhalla ... 
Pulling valhalla ... error

ERROR: for valhalla  manifest for gisops/valhalla:latest not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown
manifest for gisops/valhalla:latest not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown
```

Terraform setup

```
module "vpc" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"

  name = var.main_vpc_name
  cidr = var.main_vpc_prefix

  azs                 = var.availability_zones
  private_subnets     = var.private_subnets
  public_subnets      = var.public_subnets
  database_subnets    = var.database_subnets
  elasticache_subnets = var.elasticache_subnets
  redshift_subnets    = var.redshift_subnets

  enable_nat_gateway     = true
  single_nat_gateway     = false
  one_nat_gateway_per_az = true


  enable_vpn_gateway   = false
  enable_dns_support   = true
  enable_dns_hostnames = true

  create_database_subnet_group           = true
  create_database_subnet_route_table     = true
  create_database_internet_gateway_route = true
}
```

EB configuration

```
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "eb_env" {
  ....

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:ec2:vpc"
    name      = "VPCId"
    value     = module.vpc.vpc_id
    resource  = ""
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:ec2:vpc"
    name      = "Subnets"
    value     = join(",", sort(module.vpc.private_subnets))
    resource  = ""
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:ec2:vpc"
    name      = "ELBSubnets"
    value     = join(",", sort(module.vpc.public_subnets))
    resource  = ""
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:ec2:vpc"
    name      = "ELBScheme"
    value     = "internal"
    resource  = ""
  }


  setting {
    namespace = "aws:ec2:vpc"
    name      = "AssociatePublicIpAddress"
    value     = "false"
    resource  = ""
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration"
    name      = "SecurityGroups"
    value     = join(",", sort([module.webtraffic-sg.security_group_id]))
    resource  = ""
  }
}
```

Security group

```
module "webtraffic-sg" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/security-group/aws"
  version = "~> 4.0"

  name        = "webtraffic-sg"
  description = "Security group for EC2 instance"
  vpc_id      = module.vpc.vpc_id

  ingress_cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  ingress_rules       = ["http-80-tcp", "https-443-tcp"]
  egress_rules        = ["all-all"]

  tags = {
    Name = "${var.project_name}-sg-webtraffic"
  }

}
```

Route table

[image]

Comment: Could you verify if your private subnets have a route table, and the route table has a route with destination 0.0.0.0/0 with your NAT gateway as the target? More here: https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/nat-gateway-vpc-private-subnet

Comment: @IsuruPerera The route table already have the destination as  the nat gateway, check the edit

Comment: @user2650277 and where are you trying to pull the Docker image from?

Comment: @MarkoE from dockerhub https://hub.docker.com/r/gisops/valhalla

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is no latest tag for that Docker image. You might want to try pinning it to a version number, e.g., `gisops/valhalla:3.3.0`. There is also a note that they were moving away from Docker Hub and that GitHub packages are used: https://github.com/orgs/gis-ops/packages?repo_name=docker-valhalla.

Comment: Ahh can't believe i missed that since i had the image on local. Change the image to github and it worked just fine

Comment: @user2650277 is this already solved then? If so, would you mind stating that

Comment: @MarkoE do you mind posting it as an answer since its already solved

Comment: Done, I just used the comment above as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there is no latest tag for that Docker image. You might want to try pinning it to a version number, e.g., `gisops/valhalla:3.3.0`. There is also a note that they were moving away from Docker Hub and that GitHub [packages](https://github.com/orgs/gis-ops/packages?repo_name=docker-valhalla) are used.